# Interaction of objects in object-oriented programming

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I have been struggling trying to find a nice pattern in objected oriented programming for the following application.

Suppose you have an object that needs to be modified - maybe, the object is a house and its property price will be modified/added. This modification is based on properties `dimension_x` and `dimension_y`. But in order to set a price, we need to compare instances from other class (in this case, Houses) that have `dimension_x` and `dimension_y`.

```
class Houses(object):
  def __init__(self, dimension_x=None, dimension_y=None):
    self.dimension_x = dimension_x
    self.dimension_y = dimension_y

class City(object):
  def __init__(self, houses_without_price=None):
    self.houses_without_price = houses_without_price
    self.houses = []
  def set_dimensions(self, house1_without_price, house2_with_price):
      # calculate dimension_x, dimension_y and set these properties 
      # in an instance of Houses
  def set_price(self, house1):
     # based on dimension_x and dimension_y from our instance of Houses, 
     # add a price to the instances of self.houses_without_price
```

So basically our class Houses is just a storage for dimension_x and dimension_y. Obviously, I could use a dictionary instead. However, the interaction between the houses_without_price and a dictionary tends to be overcomplicated. For example:

```
d = [{'object': house_without_price_1, 'dimension_x': 20, 'dimension_y': 34}, 
{'object': house_without_price_2, 'dimension_x': 43, 'dimension_y': 55}...]
```

and then calculate the price property.

What is the best way to deal with this kind of interaction between objects?

Comment: What part of this system represents a single house? Where do individual houses get created?

Comment: What does `Houses` represent? It doesn't seem to represent a collection of things, each of which is a house. (If you can't describe it better than "storage for dimension_x and dimension_y, it may not be a good idea to have this class at all.)

Comment: One of the nice things about objects is that they can be stored in more than one datastructure at a time.  You can have a list of all houses, for instance, or a list of houses without a price, and completely separate of that, you can have a dictionary for accessing the houses based on their dimension that actually have a price.  Though I would probably use a dictionary with area keys and where the value is a list of houses with that area and a value.

Comment: @user2357112 A single house without price is given to you. That's what that you put into City([house_wihout_price1, house_without_price2]) So we need to add a price based on dimension_x and dimension_y that are calculated in set_dimensions.

Comment: Despite several attempts over the years I have never really gotten my head around class objects.  However, I don't understand why your object is not a house instead of houses. If you are going to have multiple instances in the object then you may as well use a dictionary - you could have a dictionary that has two keys, one house_with_price, the other house_without_price and the values of each keys are lists, each item in the list is a dictionary that has all of the known attributes of the house

Comment: Why do `set_dimensions` and `set_price` take two houses each? What is the purpose of `set_dimensions`? Are you trying to make the prices of houses be relative to the properties of the other houses on the market?

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, that's part of what I want to figure out. Maybe I don't need a class House at all. However, I tried using a dictionary and it felt a little clunky.

Comment: ...that's not the point at all (and a tuple would make more sense than a dict, but that's not the point either). I'm saying that the data stored by a `Houses` object may more properly belong to some other object, such whatever represents an individual house. A `Houses` object, or the dict you were considering replacing it with, doesn't seem to actually model a concept in your problem domain.

Comment: @Ted That's a good idea. Your proposal about having area keys and a list of houses with that area is not applicable to my real problem, though. In principle, the main objective here is to extend the houses_without_price adding a price property. The issue is that I need to do some calculation to get there.

Comment: @user2357112 You're right. set_price has only one argument. I already fixed it. However, set_dimensions require comparing a couple of houses to obtain dimension_x and dimension_y.

Comment: Why would you need to compare houses to do that? What do `dimension_x` and `dimension_y` represent, if not the dimensions of a single, specific house? What information does the price of a house actually depend on?

Comment: So wait, none of the houses have a price? Even the original set of houses in the city you are doing a cost comparison with?

Comment: @user2357112 I know it's a bit weird that the price of each house depends on the comparison of properties of other objects. Obviously, this is not the real example I'm dealing with :-)

Comment: @Ted Right. None of the houses you're getting initially have a price. Let's say you're inferring the price based on other properties you're given. As I said before, this is not a real problem. It's only an abstraction using houses and collections of houses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a manager Class.

Something that will contain all the House Classes, in let's say a list.

Then you can include a function in the manager class like:

```py
def CompareDimensions(self):
    dims = [list(instance.GetDimensions()) for instance in self.house_list]
    dims = numpy.array(dims)
    # .... futher processing on matrix
```

Assuming your house class has a function called GetDimensions, which returns a tuple of (dim_x,dim_y), you can easily build a matrix to compare these values.

Using a manager will also give you the ability to never having to directly deal with each individual house class, but you can abstract the processes from the manager. Such as creating a manager function called PushNewHouse(self,dim_x,dim_y)

A more detailed explaination:

```py
import numpy # Assuming you have numpy available

class Houses(object):
    def __init__(self, dimension_x=None, dimension_y=None):
        self.dimension_x = dimension_x
        self.dimension_y = dimension_y
    def GetDimensions(self):
        return (self.dimension_x,self.dimension_y)

class HouseManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.house_list = []
    def PushNewHouse(self,dim_x,dim_y):
        self.house_list.append(House(dim_x,dim_y))
    def CompareDimensions(self):
        dims = [list(instance.GetDimensions()) for instance in self.house_list]
        dims = numpy.array(dims)
        # .... futher processing on matrix
```

Comment: Well, this assumes that I already populated each house instance with its dimensions, right? However, getting to that point is part of the issue. However, I think I could definitely use a CompareDimensions method.

Comment: You could build on this method. Upon a comparison of the values necessary to create the dimensions, you can call a PopulateDims(self,idx,dim_x,dim_y) in the manager, where idx maps to the index of the respective house in the list. Or call PushNew(...) with the dimensions obtained from the comparator method. Just ideas, not too sure of what the plan is for these.

Comment: @RobertSmith: So... houses don't start with prices. They don't start with dimensions, either. Yet somehow, you want to compare houses to figure out the dimensions of... whatever a `Houses` is, and then use that to figure out the price of each house? What information are you even getting from each house to compute the dimensions? Your problem makes no sense.

Comment: @RyanG Interesting. Yes, this solution might be workable. I will give it a try.

Comment: @user2357112 Obviously, this is an abstraction of the real problem. However, you can think of it as Ted said in his answer (setting price based on averages of house values)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python, but in C# it would look something like this:

```
public class House(){
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Area(){
       return X*Y;
    }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure how you define a dictionary in python, but basically in C# like pseudocode, you want

```
Dictionary<double, List<House>> HousesWithValue = new Dictionary<int, List<House>>();
```

My original understanding of the process was that you would have a whole collection of houses with known values that get added to the dictionary.  You have a new house that has no value.  So when you add it to the city, first, check the dictionary based on the area, and from that list, you can get the average price from the house values.

But if none of the houses have a price, what you are basically just looking for is a way to SORT the houses that have properties that you do have values for.

// my apologies if this isn't correct python, I'm not that familiar with it.

```
house_tuples = [
    ('house1', 20, 30, 600),
    ('house2', 30, 40, 1200),
    ('house3', 30, 30, 900),
]
>>> sorted(house_tuples, key=lambda house: house[3])   # sort by area or something
```

Then you can sort the list based on area or something.  This could give you a picture of the "relative" price even if you have no knowledge of absolutes.  So if after sorting, it turns out that house3 is second, then it will have a value in the middle or whatever.

Comment: What the heck would that dict represent? Why would you want to map ints to lists of houses?

Comment: Fair point, I switched to double.  It represented area.  But this may not be applicable to what he wants anyway, not sure.